# Session IDs don't persist unless passport.js is initialized

Tags: node.js, session, express, passport.js

I have a simple, generic express app. It logs the `req.sessionID` whenever a certain route is hit. I would expect that refreshing the client page would result in the same `sessionID` being logged again. This works, *if I've imported passport and added the passport middleware after the session middleware*. If I either don't use passport at all, or I add passport middleware before the session middleware, then the `sessionID` is different every time.

I can accept that the ordering of middleware can be finicky. However, my app doesn't use passport at all, so I can't fathom why my app doesn't work if I don't require passport. **Should passport be necessary for sessions to work?**

```
    //generic express initialization
    var http = require('http');
    var express = require('express');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var passport = require('passport');
    var session = require('express-session');

    var app = express();
    var server = http.createServer(app);
    var sessionMiddleware = session({resave: false, saveUninitialized: false, secret: 'hunter2'});
    app.use(cookieParser());


    //This works:
    app.use(sessionMiddleware);
    app.use(passport.initialize());

    //This doesn't:
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(sessionMiddleware);
```

Comment: Have you tried adding sessionstore? Also: "saveUninitialized" disables saving of unmodified sessions. This might lead to the behavior you're experiencing.

Comment: Try `resave: true, saveUninitialized: true`.

Comment: Setting those to true did it! I found this in the session documentation: "Note if you are using Session in conjunction with PassportJS, Passport will add an empty Passport object to the session for use after a user is authenticated, which will be treated as a modification to the session, causing it to be saved." Authentication hasn't happened, but presumably passport is adding something else.

If one of you wants to add an answer, I'm happy to accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to `resave: true, saveUninitialized: true`

Unmodified sessions were not being saved, thus resulting in repeatedly generating new session IDs. Passport, however, was presumably doing some initialization on the session, meaning that the session was no longer unmodified.

Thanks to @Dodekeract and @Swaraj Giri for figuring the issue in their comments!