# MongoDB causing large delay with unknown findOne method - New Relic

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, newrelic

I setup newrelic to better understand what bottlenecks my app has and I found an issue that I can't seem to figure out.

Majority of my delays are being caused by `mongoDB user.fineOne` but main issue is that I can't seem to find the where in the code is it happening.

In the image below you can see the trace details for a call to `get/all/proposal` end point of my API. It first 14 method calls which are the middleware's in my server.js and after that its a **Middleware: Authenticate** within which it has **MongoDB Users findOne** and thats where the delay is.

[image]

**Code for get/all/proposals:**

```
app.get('/all/proposals',isLoggedIn,function(req, res) {
   Proposal.find().sort({proposalNo: -1}).limit(5).exec(function(err,proposal){
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       }else{
           console.log("All Proposals " + proposal);
           res.json(proposal);
       }
   });
});
```

**Now at no point that I can see am I running a User.findOne call on MongoDB at `get/all/proposals`**. Initially I thought it was the `isLoggedIn` middleware where I check if the user is in session (Passport.js) but as you can see `isLoggedIn Middleware` only takes 0.0222(ms).

The same issue appears on multiple API endpoints i.e `get/caseStudy` and its always the `user.findOne` another example below:

[image]

Can anyone help me resolve this. Please let me know if you need more detail which Im guessing you will.

**Update:**
*Server.js Code*

```
 // set up ======================================================================

require('newrelic');
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();                               // create our app w/ express
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var mongoose = require('mongoose');                     // mongoose for mongodb
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;                // set the port
var database = require('./config/db');                  // load the database config
var morgan = require('morgan');                         // log requests to the console (express4)
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');                // pull information from HTML POST (express4)
var methodOverride = require('method-override');        // simulate DELETE and PUT (express4)
var passport = require('passport');
var flash    = require('connect-flash');
var session      = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var compression = require('compression');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var busboy = require("connect-busboy");

// configuration ===============================================================


mongoose.connect(database.url);                                 // connect to mongoDB database on modulus.io
require('./config/passport')(passport);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));  
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));  // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(busboy());
app.use(compression()); //use compression
app.use(morgan('dev'));                                         // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended': true}));             // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                     // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cookieParser());                                        // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');                                  // set up ejs for templating

// required for passport
app.use(session({ secret: '',  resave: false, saveUninitialized: false })); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());                                    // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash());                                               // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session

 // routes ======================================================================

require('./routes/index.js')(app, passport); // load our routes and pass in our app and fully configured passport
//require('./routes/knowledgeBase/index.js')(app, passport);
require('./routes/bios/index.js')(app, passport);

 // listen (start app with node server.js) ======================================

app.listen(port);
console.log("App listening on port " + port);
```

**Update 2:** 
*Passport.js*

```
// config/passport.js

// load all the things we need
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var crypto = require("crypto");
var api_key = '';
var domain = '';
var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: api_key, domain: domain});
// load up the user model
var User            = require('../app/models/user');

 // expose this function to our app using module.exports
 module.exports = function(passport) {

// =========================================================================
// passport session setup ==================================================
// =========================================================================
// required for persistent login sessions
// passport needs ability to serialize and unserialize users out of session

// used to serialize the user for the session
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

// =========================================================================
// LOCAL SIGNUP ============================================================
// =========================================================================
// we are using named strategies since we have one for login and one for signup
// by default, if there was no name, it would just be called 'local'

passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        firstNameField: 'firstName',
        lastNameField: 'lastName',
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        jobTitleField: 'jobTitle',
        startDateField: 'startDate',
        passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },

    function(req, email, password, done) {

        // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
        // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
        User.findOne({
            'email': email
        }, function(err, user) {
            // if there are any errors, return the error
            if (err)
                return done(err);

            // check to see if theres already a user with that email
            if (user) {
                return done(null, false, {
                    message: 'That email is already taken.'
                });
            }
            else {

                var token = crypto.randomBytes().toString();
                // if there is no user with that email
                // create the user
                var newUser = new User();

                // set the user's local credentials
                newUser.firstName = req.body.firstName;
                newUser.lastName = req.body.lastName;
                newUser.email = email;
                newUser.password = newUser.generateHash(password); // use the generateHash function in our user model
                newUser.jobTitle = req.body.jobTitle;
                newUser.startDate = req.body.startDate;
                newUser.birthday = req.body.birthday;
                newUser.region = req.body.region;
                newUser.sector = req.body.sector;
                newUser.accountConfirmationToken = token;
                newUser.accountConfirmationTokenExpires = Date.now() + 3600000;
                newUser.accountVerified = 'false';



                // save the user
                newUser.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;
                    else {
                        return done(null, newUser);
                    }
                });
            }

        });

    }));

// =========================================================================
// LOCAL LOGIN =============================================================
// =========================================================================
// we are using named strategies since we have one for login and one for signup
// by default, if there was no name, it would just be called 'local'

passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
},
function(req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form

    // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
    // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
    User.findOne({ 'email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
        // if there are any errors, return the error before anything else
        if (err)
            return done(err);

        // if no user is found, return the message
        if (!user)
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash

        // if the user is found but the password is wrong
        if (!user.validPassword(password))
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata

        if(user.accountVerified == 'false')    
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Looks like you have not verified your account after registeration.'));
        else
            user.lastLogin = Date.now();
            user.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                    throw err;
                else {
        // all is well, return successful user
                    return done(null, user);
                }
            });
    });

}));

};
```

**Update 3:** 
`isLoggedIn` function

```
 // route middleware to make sure a user is logged in
  function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

// if user is authenticated in the session, carry on 
if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();

    // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
    res.redirect('/');
 }
```

**update 4:** 
Steps for getting proposals

**Step 1:**
First load the proposals page

```
 app.get('/proposals',isLoggedIn,function(req, res) {
    res.render('proposals.ejs', {
        user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
    });
});
```

**Step 2:**
The proposals page has a angular.js controller/factory which calls the following function on page-load to get data.

```
// =========================================================================
// FUNCTIONS TO BE RUN WHEN THE PAGE FIRST LOADS TO POPULATE FRONT-END =====
// =========================================================================
$scope.intialize = function() {
    $scope.getAllSectors();
    $scope.getLatestProposals();
}

// ===============================
// GET LATEST *5* PROPOSALS  =====
// ===============================
factory.getLatestProposals = function() {

    return $http.get('/all/proposals')
        .then(function(response) {
            //promise is fulfilled
            deferred.resolve(response.data);

            console.log("readched the filtered project service!");

            //promise is returned
            // return deferred.promise;
            return response.data;

        }, function(response) {
            deferred.reject(response);

            //promise is returned
            return deferred.promise;
        });
};
```

**Step 3:**
The `/all/proposals` route is called

```
 // =======================
//  GET All Proposals =====
//  =======================
app.get('/all/proposals',isLoggedIn,function(req, res) {
   Proposal.find().sort({proposalNo: -1}).limit(5).exec(function(err,proposal){
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       }else{
           console.log("All Proposals " + proposal);
           res.json(proposal);
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: Are you using Mongoose?

Comment: @CervEd yes. Do you think that could be causing this?

Comment: No idea honestly. Here's what I can see, you're responding to the get request by calling isLoggedIn and the anonymous function invoking a Mongoose model. What about before this, is there any other part of the app that get's invoked on the get requests?

Comment: @CervEd No I can't find anything that runs before `isLoggedIn` although there are scripts that run after the page loads but they are once the page has loaded. I honestly can't figure it out and it's slowing my app quite a bit. It looks like its running a authentication middleware right after it finishes running through the server.js file.

Comment: @Skywalker Can you please add the middleware configuration for your Express app?

Comment: @VladZ. Please see updated question for the code. I hope thats what you were asking for. Let me know if you need anything else please. Thank you!

Comment: @Skywalker Thank you for the update! Could you please also add the passport configuration? As it appears from the pictures you provided, the `findOne` query is executed as part of the `authenticate` middleware, which makes me believe that you have a LocalStrategy implemented. Thus, that query is part of the authentication process that you configured for passport.

Comment: @VladZ. I've updated the question with the code you requested. You are correct I do have the `local-strategy` implemented. Apologies for messy code its still in development. And Thank you for the help!!

Comment: @Skywalker Could you also post the content of the `isLoggedIn` middleware that you are applying on the route?

Comment: @VladZ. please see the updated question for the `isLoggedIn` code.

Answer (score 6):

After looking at the code that you provided, it appears that the `.findOne()` that appears in your performance log is the one performed when searching for a user and authenticating him.

Thus, it appears that the performance bottleneck is occurring in one of the below 2 queries:

```
/*
 * LOCAL LOGIN
 */
// find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
    // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
    User.findOne({ 'email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
...


/*
 * LOCAL SIGNUP
 */
    // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
    // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
    User.findOne({
        'email': email
...
```

I see that in both of your passport local strategies you are searching against the `email` field, thus you can improve performance by creating an index on that field.

To try optimizing the `LOCAL LOGIN` findOne query even more, you can try adding an index for the `users` collection on the `email` field, if you haven't already:

```
// This index will optimize queries that search against the {email} field
db.users.createIndex({ email: 1});
```

**UPDATE #1**

I found a related [Stack Overflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31375964/session-ids-dont-persist-unless-passport-js-is-initialized) that might be the answer to your performance issue -  you should update the below line in your `express.js` configuration:

```
app.use(session({ secret: '',  resave: false, saveUninitialized: false }));
```

to

```
app.use(session({ secret: '',  resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }));
```

I also managed to find these notes regarding the `resave` and `saveUninitalized` properties in the Express JS documentation:

**[saveUninitialized](https://github.com/expressjs/session#saveuninitialized)**

> Forces a session that is "uninitialized" to be saved to the store. A
>   session is uninitialized when it is new but not modified. Choosing
>   false is useful for implementing login sessions, reducing server
>   storage usage, or complying with laws that require permission before
>   setting a cookie. Choosing false will also help with race conditions
>   where a client makes multiple parallel requests without a session.
>
> The default value is true, but using the default has been deprecated,
>   as the default will change in the future. Please research into this
>   setting and choose what is appropriate to your use-case.
>
> **Note if you are using Session in conjunction with PassportJS, Passport will add an empty Passport object to the session for use
>   after a user is authenticated, which will be treated as a modification
>   to the session, causing it to be saved. This has been fixed in
>   PassportJS 0.3.0**

**[resave](https://github.com/expressjs/session#resave)**

> Forces the session to be saved back to the session store, even if the
>   session was never modified during the request. Depending on your store
>   this may be necessary, **but it can also create race conditions where
>   a client makes two parallel requests to your server and changes made
>   to the session in one request may get overwritten when the other
>   request ends, even if it made no changes** (this behavior also depends
>   on what store you're using).
>
> The default value is true, but using the default has been deprecated,
>   as the default will change in the future. Please research into this
>   setting and choose what is appropriate to your use-case. Typically,
>   you'll want false.
>
> How do I know if this is necessary for my store? The best way to know
>   is to check with your store if it implements the touch method. If it
>   does, then you can safely set resave: false. If it does not implement
>   the touch method and your store sets an expiration date on stored
>   sessions, then you likely need resave: true.

Comment: Thank you so much! That really helps a lot. I do have one question though  the `user.findOne` in  both `local-signup` and `local-login` are only run when signing up or logging-in which you do once.  Do you think they are being run with every API request? At `get/all/proposals` I authenticate the user by looking in session do you think the code in passport.js is being run as well? Again Thanks!

Comment: After logging a user in, passport binds an object to the `req` object = `req.user`. Thus, you can simply check if that property has been created on the `req` object, signaling that a user is logged in. Furthermore, you can create a new middleware that simply checks if `req.user` exists and returns `next()`.

Comment: Im currently using the `isLoggedIn` function to check if the user is in session. But the `local-signup` and `local-login` code is only run at login & signup. It couldn't be running at any other API call. Thanks!

Comment: @Skywalker After taking a closer look at the screenshots you provided, it appears that the `authenticate` middleware (which I'm guessing the `passport.authenticate` method) gets called before processing the route. What are the steps that you take before accessing `GET /all/proposals`?

Comment: I've updated my question for the steps included in `Get all/proposals` as it was long rather then trying to fit it in a comment. Hope it helps!

Comment: @Skywalker So are you trying to hit that route before logging in? Or are you first logging in before? Also, could you try moving `require('./config/passport')(passport);` right before `app.use(passport.initialize());`? Also, after indexing the database, did you notice any performance improvement?

Comment: No before the user can do anything within the app they go through a login page and login and then can access the proposals page. Apologies I should've included that in my update. Okay I will try moving it. Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125755/discussion-between-vlad-z-and-skywalker).